# MySQL Синхронизация ячейки с колличеством строк

Tags: mysql, sql

Ранее я пробовал реализовывать 2 варианта...

- Создание новой строки в таблице и прибавление на 1 в ячейке другой таблицы как инджикатор колличества строк. (Итог разсинхрон реального количества строк и числа в ячейке).
- Каждый запрос подсчитывать колличество строк и выдает их (Итог после 2-3 тысяч строк возникают проблемы к скорости загрузки, а на практике у меня ваыходили вообще по 10-15к строк... что занимало по 3-5 секунд на запрос).

В итоге мне нужен вариант который будет выполняться быстро как первый но выдавать точные данные как второй вариант.

Какие есть предложения? Буду очень благодарен!!!

Comment: Если то, как Вы пытались решать задачу - более-менее понятно (скорее, правда, всё же менее), то вот сама задача, которую Вы пытались решать, непонятна совершенно.

Comment: Лайки и коменты как правильно выводить? Как их прапвильно считать? ибо их очень много и пересчитывать ресурсо-затратно а хратить их колличество не точное знаечение